# Because I can't bring back the value of a pointer after adding it to an array of interfaces

Tags: arrays, go, pointers

I'm studying "pointers". I can print the memory location and variable value normally using the "&" and "*" operators. The problem is that I can't print the value when the memory address is inside an interface array. I can extract the memory location but not the value. How to make?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var name string = "Name User"


    var pointer *string
    var array []interface{}
    
    
    
    pointer = &name
    array = append(array, &name)
    
    
    
    fmt.Println("Memory address: ",  pointer)   // OK
    fmt.Println("Variable value: ", *pointer)   // OK
    
    
    
    fmt.Println("Memory address: ",  array[0])  // OK
    fmt.Println("Variable value: ", *array[0])  // ERROR
        
}
```

Erro:

```
invalid indirect of array[0] (type interface {})
```

Comment: Like the error says, you can't dereference an `interface{}`. To get a concrete type, you use a [Type Assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15), Spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

Answer (score 0):

After reading the links suggested by [JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb):

- [Type Assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15);
- [Documentation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions).

  The change was as follows:

```
fmt.Println("Variable value: ", *array[0].(*string))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).